# I want to create a nested datetime dictionary with the first level of keys being the years and the second being months

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataset which contains string objects, floating type, and dates like the following:

```
----------------------------------------------
|str obj col.| Int. Col | Float Col| Date Col|
----------------------------------------------
| str obj.   | Int.     |   Float  | Date Obj|                              
|---------------------------------------------
| str obj.   | Int.     |   Float  | Date Obj|
|---------------------------------------------
| str obj.   | Int.     |   Float  | Date Obj|
----------------------------------------------
|      .     |    .     |     .    |    .    |
----------------------------------------------
|      .     |    .     |     .    |    .    |
----------------------------------------------
|      .     |    .     |     .    |    .    |
----------------------------------------------
| str obj.   |  Int.    |   Float  | Date Obj|
----------------------------------------------
```

The date objects have the format mm/dd/yyyy. I was able to group the dates by month year using pandas. I achieved this by creating two lists. One list contains all the year month labels as strings, the other contained a list of dataframes. I combined them into a dictionary containing a list of DataFrames. I achieved this using the following:

```
L2  = sorted(set(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m').tolist()))
L3 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'))
Dict_2 = dict(zip(L2, L3))
```

I then created an empty dictionary just containing the years. So, I used the following to generate this:

```
L1 = sorted(set(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y').tolist()))
Dict_1 = dict.fromkeys(L1)
```

The goal is to combine Dict_1 and Dict_2 into a dictionary categorized by year, and then month. To reach this aim I used the following:

```
for year in Dict_1.keys():
    for month_year in Dict_2.keys():
        if search(str(year), str(month_year)):
           Dict_1[year].update({month_year, Dict_2[month_year]})
```

The rationale behind this was that if the year string matched the month_year string, then add this new subkey to Dict_1.

**The expected output was:**

```
Dict_1 = {'2008': {'2008-01': [DataFrame Obj], '2008-02':[DataFrame Obj],...,'2008-12':[DataFrame Obj]}, ..., '2019': {'2019-01': [DataFrame Obj], '2019-02':[DataFrame Obj],...,'2019-12':[DataFrame Obj]}}
```

**However I received the following error:**

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

I thought this method would spontaneously generate subkeys and replace the none value contained inside this dictionary key, but it does not do this at all. Which leads me to the following three questions:

Firstly, how can I add this subkey from Dict_2 to this empty key in Dict_1? Secondly, how can I add the original information contained inside my Dict_2 subkey into my Dict_1 key? Finally, is there a better way of doing this other than using my current method? Possibly dictionary comprehension or some vectorized operation in pandas?

The goal is a to have a dictionary, which has the years, then the month-year, then a list of DataFrame Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Addressing the for loop only

I wasn't able to fully reproduce what you're doing. Assuming that your step prior to the for loop return the correct output, this should work:

```
for year in L1:
    months_dfs_in_year = []
    for month_year, df_obj in Dict_2.items():
        if search(year, month_year):
            months_dfs_in_year.append((month_year, df_obj))
            Dict_1[year] = dict(months_dfs_in_year)
```

**Note:** Generally you should iterate over something and make changes on it while doing so. Therefore, I replaced `Dict_1.keys()` with `L1` (which I would have named something more descriptive like "years").

#### To explain, here's your code

```
for year in Dict_1.keys():
    for month_year in Dict_2.keys():
        if search(str(year), str(month_year)):
           Dict_1[year].update({month_year, Dict_2[month_year]})
```

- `Dict_1[year]`: `dict[key]` [returns the *value* associated with *key*.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)

  - Returns `None` because Dict_1 has no *values*, only *keys*.
  - `Dict_1[year] = ...` works because it makes the the *value* what follows after the equal sign for the key that is *year*.
- `{month_year, Dict_2[month_year])` [is a set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), not a dictionary

  - A [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) would be `{month_year: Dict2[month_year]}`
- `dict().update()` [updates the *key: value* pairs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-51), but you're trying to return a dictionary nested in a dictionary.

  - If everything else worked except for this, and you had written `Dict_1.update({month_year: Dict2[month_year]})` you'd get a dictionary like:

    ```
      {'2008': None, '2009': None, ..., '2008-12': [dataframe], ...}
    ```

##### Things I added/changed

- I removed str() around year and month_year in search() they should already be strings. It seemed unnecessary, if it is needed, add it back.
- Without the list `months_dfs_in_year`, the end result would only be the last `month_year: [dataframe]` pair.

  - the output for each *year* key would be something like:

    ```
      {'2008': {'2008-12': [dataframe]}, '2009': {'2009-12': [dataframe]}, ...}
    ```
- The list is in the loop after `for year in L1` so it "resets" for each `year` in `L1`. Otherwise, we'd end up with something like:

  ```
  {'2008': {'2008-01': [dataframe], ..., '2008-12': [dataframe]}, 
   '2009': {'2008-01': [dataframe], ..., '2009-12': [dataframe]}, 
   '2010': {'2008-01': [dataframe], ..., '2010-12': [dataframe]}}
  ```

### A [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) version:

And, mainly because I wrote this first, but in case you/someone else might find it useful.

Using this, you would not need to create a list or "pre-create" Dict_1.

```
Dict_1 = {year: {month_year: df_obj
                 for month_year, df_obj in Dict_2.items() if search(year, month_year)
                 }
          for year in L1
          }
```

Comment: I solved the problem using a solution similar to the dictionary comprehension version. My solution was as follows: `new_dict = {y_key {m_key: month_obj[m_key] for m_key in month_obj if search(str(y_key), str(m_key))} for y_key in year_obj}` I did not have to access the keys. Why are you accessing the keys in this particular case?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I accidentally left that in there - I initially had Dict_1 instead of L1 in the dictionary comprehension.